# Help with doubly Linked List in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, double

so I am having a little trouble wrapping my head around this problem.
I have created a doubly linked list called dlist (which contains a linknode helper class). I have another class called DeckOps that is used along with the linked list.  dlist already contains functions to insertFront, removeFront, insertRear, removeRear and a print function. Currently I have it working where I pass a filename to DeckOps, which then reads in a file, inputing an int into each link node of the list (putting in from rear to hold same order as in the file).

Now my problem, I need to be able to find a number in the list, so I assume I will need a find function. and then I need to be able to select everything below a number and swap it with everything above a number. a seperate swap function would be nice i think?
My main issue here is how to select a group and swap with another group.

thanks

example:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 find 6 find 4 swap everything below 6, with everything above 4
7 8 9 4 5 6 1 2 3 result
EDIT:
just realized in writing out this example is the program needs to know if the number i search for is closer to the top or to the bottom.

not looking for a solution, just some help.

Comment: Is this homework? If not, why are you not using `std::list<>`?

Comment: I suggest you first try write your find function, and test it fully, before looking into the swap. I feel that you should try to write a find() before coming to us.

Comment: The selection can be done with a list that instead of int's stores pointers to list nodes.
But what do you mean by swapping?
Can you give an example?

Comment: So if your list is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, and you select 3, would this become `[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]` (effectively reversing the list)? Or do you mean `[4, 5, 6, 3, 2, 1]`?

Comment: i mean if my list contains 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 after the swap happens on everything below 5 and everything above 3 it would be 6 7 3 4 5 1 2 .

find function is in the works, not a problem on that one really.

Comment: @Skurmedel, I think the desired swap function is to apply to _pair_ of locations. So two numbers must be found, and the list is _not_ modified between those two locations. But the rest of the list is modified, by swapping the two subsequences outside of the found range.

Comment: @Aaron: You seem to be right. Never seen such a swap before.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly interpret what you mean by "swap", you need to implement [list splicing](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibref/list.html#idx795).  You can either move the range at the start to a new list, then move it back to the end of the original list, or you can do it all at once.  The latter is only slightly more complicated, mostly in terms of preconditions that the insertion point isn't within the range to be moved.

[Example with std::list](http://ideone.com/Pbxjw):

```
int main() {
  std::list<int> L;
  for (int n = 0; n != 10; ++n) L.push_back(n);
  std::list<int>::iterator x = std::find(L.begin(), L.end(), 6);
  assert(x != L.end());  // We know this is true in this example.

  std::list<int> temp;
  temp.splice(temp.end(), L, L.begin(), x);
  temp.splice(temp.begin(), L, x);
  L.splice(L.end(), temp);

  std::copy(L.begin(), L.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
  7, 8, 9, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
# ^-----^     ^--------------^
#   \... swapped with .../
```

Comment: but what if i want to keep more numbers in the middle than just the 6?

Comment: @adsderek: Then do that.  Set up your iterator ranges and move them where you like.  List::splice takes either a single iterator or a range (I have examples of both above).

Comment: yeah i just realized how i could do it, with an iterator x like u have, and an iterator y, at the other value. both examples in the link you provided? now what if I wanted to switch two numbers? or rather, move and element up or down in the list how ever many times?

Comment: i would like to return to here for help, i am having an issue with the above, I can not figure out how to get past the idea of not knowing whether a number i use is at the front or back. say i create a list 1 4 5 6 2 4 7 8 and i set my range from 5 to 4, how will i ever know which one is at the front and which one is at the back? seeing as how i need everything outside to change places and everything in the middle to stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just curios ... is there any reason not to use an STL container class?

Do you really need to reinvent the wheel? Do you have a requirement that you think STL can't handle? Do you think you can code "better" then the STL? Are you perhaps coding for an embedded device or obscure processor with no STL support?

Even if not STL, did you consider Boost++ ?

You may be asking the wrong question here ... perhaps you should be asking yourself if can spare time from the rest of your development to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: i could use STL, but already had my own doubly linked list from an assignment in the past.  So i figured creating my own would give me a little more flexibility than using one in STL, aside from that I am not too familiar with using the stl::list .  I thought I might run into problems using the STL list because of the operations.

Comment: +1 However, I strongly recommend you get out of that mindset, for the following reasons:  1) no offence, but your code is unlikely to be as good as the STL, written & fine-tuned by some real pros. 2) nor as flexible. STL really is flexible and should be able to do anything you want it to. Otherwise, why would thye release it? It is supposed to be "all things, to all men".  3) it will need less testing than your code (theoretically none) and should be smaller & faster. 4) you will get a lot more support for STL than your own code (and can google for answers, instead of asking questions)

Comment: 5) you are more likely to land a job with STL experience (although coding lists tends to crop up in interviews, I can't believe that professionals waste money doing so) 6) and probably the most important - your time is precious. Don't waste it reinventing the wheel. Spend you tiem doing more interesting things (liek documentation ;-)

Comment: Your only real argument for coding your won class is that it might take too long to learn STL. But you only have to learn it once & can use it forever. And it is designed to be easy to learn.  Just my 2 cents worth

Comment: yah i am now using the stl :)

Comment: He he, good news!  It really makes sense in the long run. It also makes sense to spent a little time looking at Boost++.  At first glance you might be wary of using an external library, but many of the contributors are members of the standardization committee for C++ and some of the Boost++ stuff is expected to make it to future versions of C++/STL (I personally like the hash class & the Finite State Machines). It also has a good unit test suite.

Comment: Btw, you can close this question now, by awarding an answer ;-)           If you can't get it working with STL then post a new question & you will receive a lot more help than for this question.